# Is it possible store/retrieve bit data from file using VB.Net BinaryWriter?

Tags: vb.net, binary, data-storage

Ok, I need to store/retrieve a bit from a data table of 3.268.760 bits long.

```
Using w As New BinaryWriter(File.Open("test.bin", FileMode.Create))
    for x = 1 to 3268760
        For i = 1 To 3268760
            w.Write(countBits(bitLikeness(u(i), u(x))) > 10)
        Next
     Next
End Using
```

the `w.write(?)` stores a boolean value meaning 0/1 for false/true values, but Vb.net seems to use an whole byte to store this data which is too expensive for my table (3.268.760^2)

Is there a pratical way to store/retrive single bits from a file using vb.net? (meaning as little as possible conversion to other types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the BinaryReader/Writer is probably your best option.

```
Public Class BitWriter

    Private ReadOnly mBinaryWriter As BinaryWriter

    Private mBuffer As Integer
    Private mBufferCount As Integer

    Public Sub New(binaryWriter As BinaryWriter)
        mBinaryWriter = binaryWriter
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteBit(bit As Boolean)

        If mBufferCount = 32 Then

            mBinaryWriter.Write(mBuffer)

            mBuffer = 0
            mBufferCount = 0

        End If

        If bit Then mBuffer = mBuffer Or (1 << mBufferCount)

        mBufferCount += 1

    End Sub

    Public Sub Flush()

        mBinaryWriter.Write(mBuffer)

        mBuffer = 0
        mBufferCount = 0

    End Sub

End Class
```

And to read the bits back

```
Public Class BitReader

    Private ReadOnly mBinaryReader As BinaryReader

    Private mBuffer As Integer
    Private mBufferCount As Integer

    Public Sub New(binaryReader As BinaryReader)
        mBinaryReader = binaryReader
        mBuffer = -1
    End Sub

    Public Function ReadBit() As Boolean

        If mBuffer = -1 OrElse mBufferCount = 8 Then

            mBuffer = mBinaryReader.ReadInt32()
            mBufferCount = 0

        End If

        Dim toReturn As Boolean = ((mBuffer >> mBufferCount) And 1) = 1

        mBufferCount += 1

        Return toReturn

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Seems reasonable to me @Thomas, but how to **retrive** data afterwards (to a more complete answer).

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clear it contains two classes (and cleaned it up a bit)

Comment: Well your anwers is rigth but unfornatelly the number is really huge meaning that even storing that as bits it would requeire 1.336Tb. But i may find a work around...